# Why is only my last object being updated in loop in object

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, logic

I have two objects, One is an array that looks like this:

```
let value = [123,500];
```

The other is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
let mapObject = [
  {id:123,name:"Thing 1"},
  {id:444,name:"Thing 2"},
  {id:500,name:"Thing 3"},
  {id:777,name:"Thing 4"}
];
```

The goal of the next function is to iterate over the mapObject and if the id matches any of the elements in the value, then set a new property called 'on' to true, otherwise set it to false.  Here is the code for that:

```
for (let i in mapObject) {
  for (let j in value) {
    if (mapObject[i].id == value[j]) {
      mapObject[i].on = true;
    } else {
      mapObject[i].on = false;
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect is this:

```
[
  {id:123,name:"Thing 1",on:true},
  {id:444,name:"Thing 2",on:false},
  {id:500,name:"Thing 3",on:true},
  {id:777,name:"Thing 4",on:false}
]
```

However what I am actually getting it this:

```
[
  {id:123,name:"Thing 1",on:false},
  {id:444,name:"Thing 2",on:false},
  {id:500,name:"Thing 3",on:true},
  {id:777,name:"Thing 4",on:false}
]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Note: i just tried this directly in the command line and got the Property 'on' does not exist on type...  error.  This can be solved by initializing the object with the on values all set to false, but it still has the same result.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd recommend using a `for-of` loop to iterate over the values in an array, or the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop logic is not good. Once you update the value to true you should break from the inner loop.

```
for (let i in mapObject) {
    for (let j in value) {
        if (mapObject[i].id == value[j]) {
            mapObject[i].on = true;
            break;
        } else {
            mapObject[i].on = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that once you update the value to `true` you loop again with the same `mapObject[i].id` and test it against a new value from `value[j]`.

Comment: I would put the `mapObject[i].on = false;` before the `for`, to ensure the fields has a value, as if the value is the first one marched `on` will remain undefined

Comment: Dang it,  I thought I was having some fundamental misunderstanding with typescript.  turns out i'm just a bonehead. thanks.

Comment: Don't worry mate, these things happen.